# Unable to assign Dynamic values in chartjs in lwc? need to set the condition to display chart

Tags: javascript, community, lightning-web-components, charts, chartjs

```
    javaScript file:

    import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
    import chartjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/chart';
    import momentjs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/moment';
    import chart from '@salesforce/apex/loanController.chart';
     
     
    export default class impactChart extends LightningElement {
        
    @track error='';
    @track chart;
    @track config;
    @api recordId;
    @track loading=true;
    @track dataPresent=true;
    @track LLostjobsValue=[];
    @track LCreatedjobsValue=[];
    @track LMaintainedjobsValue=[];
    @track ALostjobsValue=[];
    @track ACreatedjobsValue=[];
    @track AMiantainedjobsValue=[];
    @track isChartJsInitialized;
    @track impacts;

    chartjsInitialized = false;
    
    connectedCallback(){
        this.loanImpactjobs();
      
        this.config = {
            type:'horizontalBar',
            data:
                {
                labels: ["Lost","Maintained","Created"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                      label: "Actual",
                      backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
                      data:[this.LCreatedjobsValue,this.LLostjobsValue,this.LMaintainedjobsValue]
                      
                    }, {
                      label: "Estimate",
                      backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
                      data:[this.ACreatedjobsValue,this.ALostjobsValue,this.AMiantainedjobsValue]
                    }
                    
                  ]
                },
             options: {
                  legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: false
                    }]
                }
            }
        };
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        console.log("hi");
        if (this.chartjsInitialized) {
            return;
        }

        this.chartjsInitialized = true;
        this.createChart();
        console.log("bye")
    }

    

   
    updateChart(){
        this.chart.data.datasets[0].data = this.LMaintainedjobsValue;
        this.chart.data.datasets[1].data = this.LCreatedjobsValue;
        this.chart.data.datasets[2].data = this.LLostjobsValue;
        this.chart.data.datasets[3].data = this.ACreatedjobsValue;
        this.chart.data.datasets[4].data = this.ALostjobsValue;
        this.chart.data.datasets[5].data = this.AMiantainedjobsValue;
     
        this.chart.update();
    }
     createChart(){
        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, momentjs)
        ]).then(() => {
            Promise.all([
                loadScript(this, chartjs)
            ]).then(() => {
                const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                this.template.querySelector('div.chart').appendChild(canvas);
                const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
            }).catch(error => {
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
                        message: error.message,
                        variant: 'error',
                    }),
                );
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error loading momentJS',
                    message: error.message,
                    variant: 'error',
                }),
            );
        });      
    }
    loanImpactjobs() {
         
           this.loading=true;
      
           chart({id:this.recordId }).then(data=>{
           if(data!==''&& data!==undefined){
         this.impacts=JSON.stringify(data);
         var dObject=JSON.parse(this.impacts);  
         console.log(dObject);
         console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.impacts)));                  
               this.LCreatedjobsValue=dObject["Total_Jobs_Created__c"];
             
               this.LLostjobsValue=dObject["Total_Jobs_Lost__c"];
                
               this.LMaintainedjobsValue=dObject["Total_Jobs_Maintained__c"];
             
               this.ACreatedjobsValue=dObject["Application__r"]["Total_Jobs_Created__c"];
          
               this.ALostjobsValue=dObject.Application__r.Total_Jobs_Lost__c;
               
               this.AMiantainedjobsValue=dObject["Application__r"]["Total_Jobs_Maintained__c"];
               
              
           }
           } ).catch(error => {
               this.errorMessage(error);
           });
       }
        

    errorMessage(msg){
        this.loading=false;
        this.dataPresent=false;
        this.error=msg;
        console.log(msg);
      }
}
```

---

html

```
<template> 
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="chart slds-m-around_medium" lwc:dom="manual"></div>         
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

### apex

```
 @AuraEnabled
    public static SObject chart(Id id){
   sObject entities= [SELECT Total_Jobs_Created__c,Total_Jobs_Lost__c,Total_Jobs_Maintained__c, Application__r.Total_Jobs_Created__c,Application__r.Total_Jobs_Lost__c,Application__r.Total_Jobs_Maintained__c
  FROM Loan__c  WHERE Id=:id];

   return entities;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no error but chart is blank if i given dynamic value

Comment: Can you check if the data is loaded before the chart is initialized?

Comment: Iam not sure how to check,but if i given number values it is working ,dynamic only empty chart appear

Comment: Add console logs in `createChart()` and `loanImpactjobs()` and check which is getting called first.

Comment: yes i did ,i got **loanImpactjobs()** first then only **createChart()** came has second

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the below code inside `loanImpactjobs()` inside `if(data!==''&& data!==undefined){` block.

```
this.config = {
    type:'horizontalBar',
    data:
        {
        labels: ["Lost","Maintained","Created"],
        datasets: [
            {
              label: "Actual",
              backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
              data:[this.LCreatedjobsValue,this.LLostjobsValue,this.LMaintainedjobsValue]
              
            }, {
              label: "Estimate",
              backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
              data:[this.ACreatedjobsValue,this.ALostjobsValue,this.AMiantainedjobsValue]
            }
            
          ]
        },
     options: {
          legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                stacked: false
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

Reason is `chart({id:this.recordId })` is asynchronous(Promise in JS) and result of the data will be available only when `.then()` is executed.

In your existing code,

```
this.loanImpactjobs();
// below code is executed before data is loaded from wired method, so all values are null.
this.config = {
    ...
    ...
};
```

---

**Also, instead of nesting two, you can use `Promise.All()` to load static resources like below.**

```
Promise.all([
    loadScript(this, momentjs),
    loadScript(this, chartjs)
]).then(() => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.template.querySelector('div.chart').appendChild(canvas);
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.chart = new window.Chart(ctx, this.config);
}).catch(error => {
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Error loading ChartJS',
            message: error.message,
            variant: 'error',
        }),
    );
});
```

---

**Reusable Chart Component**

You can use a separate component to create and load the chart and include that in another component that loads the data, say `Chart`. So you will load data in the parent component and pass it down to the child component. So you keep all your data and chart logic separated. Also, you can reuse that `Chart` component to generate different types of charts.

I have demonstrated that in my blog post: [Bar Chart In Lightning Web Component Using Chartjs](https://sftrailmixer.blogspot.com/2020/04/bar-chart-in-lightning-web-component-lwc-bar-chartjs.html)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110355/discussion-on-answer-by-rahul-gawale-unable-to-assign-dynamic-values-in-chartjs).